# Show div on successful response

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get the success div to show after the php data is successfully sent to the server, only its updating but the div isn't showing.

Can somebody show me where I'm going wrong. I've looked around stack overflow and tried many different solutions with no luck.

```
<div id= "infomsg" style="display: none;">Updated Successfully! </div>

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "validate.php",
cache: false,
dataType: "json",
data: dataString,
success: function(Success){
  $('#infomsg').show(Success)
        }
        });


if (isset($_POST))
{


    $first=$_POST['first'];
    $middle=$_POST['middle'];
    $last=$_POST['last'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $lives=$_POST['lives'];
    $Gender=$_POST['Gender'];
    $about=$_POST['about'];
    $fav_track=$_POST['fav_track'];
    $fav_bands=$_POST['fav_bands'];


$sql3 = "UPDATE user SET first='$first',middle='$middle',last='$last',email='$email',lives='$lives',Gender='$Gender', about='$about', fav_track='$fav_track', fav_bands='$fav_bands' WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
        $res3 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

         //Writes the photo to the server 
 if($res3) 
 { 
 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo '<div id= "infomsg" style="display: none;">Updated Successfully! </div>'; 
 }else{ 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem updating the Information, Contact se7ern@se7ern.co.uk with REF:#1112-Validate."; 
 }




 }
```

Comment: What is "Success" returning? Is it returning HTML?  You should just show the div without the message.

Comment: It is yes. so is it html(success)

Comment: So, you are replacing whatever was in the div with the returned value, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just want to show the **`<div>`** you do not have to pass any parameter in "`show()`" method.

You can just do it with below mentioned approach :

```
<div id="infomsg" style="display: none;">Updated Successfully!</div>

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "validate.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (Success) {
        $('#infomsg').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass argument to the `show()` method, if you only want to show the div do just:

```
$('#infomsg').show();
```

If you need some information returned from the server you would need to dig into the `Success` which is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Just show the div:
     $('#infomsg').show();

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that the success function is entered first - place an `alert();` statement in the block.

...

```
success: function() {
    alert('a');
}
```

...

If that works, then try and change its CSS property:

```
$('#infomsg').css('display', 'inline');
```

Comment: Alert is not even working. 
Shall I post my php end?

Comment: Before that, try running your PHP code standalone - try putting an `echo 'a';` statement at the top of that PHP file. Do you see output?